# What would cause a Cesium 3D-Tiles tileset to not even request it's content?

Tags: python, gdal, tiles, 3d, cesium

I am generating an I3DM through Python. I know that the I3DM is probably ok, since the 3d-tiles-tools allow me to extract the binary GLTF file from it. However, when I go to render the tileset in Cesium, it shows in the Web Tools Inspector it doesn't even request the i3dm file. It requests the tileset.json, but that's all. What would cause this to happen? Here's my tileset:

```
{
  "asset": {
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "properties": {
  },
  "geometricError": 70,
  "root": {
    "refine": "ADD",
    "boundingVolume": {
      "region": [
        -2591020.1425219355,
        1588193.8474433378,
        318979.8574780645,
        -3805806.1525566624,
        0,
        100000
      ]
    },
    "geometricError": 0,
    "content": {
      "uri": "myi3DM.i3dm"
    }
  }
}
```

The I3DM's feature table only has the POSITION variable in it's binary.

Comment: Your BoundingVolume looks odd to me if compared with the specification https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/3d-tiles/tree/master/specification#bounding-volumes.

Comment: You are right, I was getting the region's values wrong. But I have no idea how to convert (Lat,Lon,Height) to EPSG 4979. gdaltransform doesn't work for it either. It just echoes the input coordinates.

Comment: Hi Sam you could use shapely or ogr to do the coordinate transformation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943093/library-to-perform-coordinate-system-transformations/27943394#27943394